# Rendering HTML in rails without actually displaying it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, render, erb

My current project requires me to assemble a .zip file containing HTML and text-only templates for a user to download, for importing into an email marketing program.

I've inherited this project, and currently the code uses a "fake" model (that is a model that does not directly correlate to a database table), in which it stores the entire template in a string, using dynamic variables to populate certain areas.  The "fake" model then has a method for creating a zip file.

It seems to me that there has to be a better way to do this.  I was wondering if there was a way to move the template into a .erb/haml file, and then write a method that would populate the file in preparation for being zipped up?  Basically, is there a way to render an HTML and text file, without actually having to display them?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "fake" model or controller? Normally the controller is responsible for the rendering and not the model.

Comment: It's a class located in the models folder, but it isn't associated with a database object.  Instead, it requires the the ID of an actual model to be passed to it when the class is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write the action and view to render the html and text as normal then use the render_to_string method to assign the content to strings

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string

Then you can run the Model method (hopefully a Class method) to create the zip file using the content you now have in instance variables

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [cells plugin](http://cells.rubyforge.org/).